# CSS border not working in Chrome but working in IE

Tags: css, colors, border

I have the following code which works fine in ie8 but not in Chrome. I want the border to show and it is not:

```
.sitewidth{
width:1000px;
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
border-left: 1px #EE6A00 solid;
border-right:1px #EE6A00 solid;
overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that it's not showing high enough in Chrome without a height?

What's in the html code? Sometime it will require a `<br clear="all" />` before the end of the closing div so that the whole div shows on screen.

I'm not too sure `min-height` will have any affect if it's followed by `height:auto;` ?

Comment: thanks the br worked but it border gets stuck and does not show for the whole page, http://www.incard.com.au/newsite/ e.g. my screen is 1920x1080 so my screen does not get the border all the way, it stops aftr the paypal logo/image

Comment: For me on the same resolution in Google Chrome it goes the whole way down the page?

Comment: Just saw this. Screen res is 1440x900, and the border extends past the PayPal button.

Answer (score 0):

At the first, please define a background-color for your box to be sure it can be shown fine. Then, I suggest you remove other features at the first and solve your problem.
Do it with something like this:

```
.box {
   background-color:silver;
   width:1000px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

If this can work fine, you can modify it with other properties.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened because I used `0.5px` instead of `1px`. There is no such thing as half a pixel.